# Request do MooTools: onSuccess não é disparado

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs, mootools

Estou usando KnockoutJS em conjunto com o MooTools, mas estou tento problemas com o [Request](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request).

```html
  <div class="form-group">
      <select data-bind="options: classificacoes, optionsText: ds_classificacao, optionsValue: id"></select>
  </div>

  <script>
      ko.applyBindings( new App.viewModels.selectsProcedimentos() );
  </script>
```

```js
App.requests.classificacoes = new Request.JSON({
    url: "/classificacoes.json",
    method: "get"
});

App.viewModels.selectsProcedimentos = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        this.classificacoes = ko.observableArray([]);
        App.requests.classificacoes.send({
            onSuccess: function(classificacoes) {
                this.classificacoes.push(classificacoes);
                alert("baixou");
            }
        });
        alert("initialize");
    }
});
```

O que acontece aqui é que o `initialize` é disparado, mas o método `onSuccess` não, sendo que o `<select>` fica vazio. Porém na aba *network* das ferramentas de desenvolvimento dá pra ver que o JSON é baixado. Não há erros no console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem de defenir o handler do evento `onSuccess` dentro da Classe Request. O método `send()` aceita dados para passar para o lado do servidor e opções para a Classe, mas não novos Eventos da Classe. Dê uma olhada [na documentação](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request) e repare na diferença entre options e events.

Teste assim:

```
App.requests.classificacoes = new Request.JSON({
    url: "/classificacoes.json",
    method: "get",
    onSuccess: function(classificacoes) {
        // this.classificacoes.push(classificacoes); // acho que aqui está a usar o this de maneira incorreta
        alert("baixou");
    }
});

App.viewModels.selectsProcedimentos = new Class({
    initialize: function() {
        this.classificacoes = ko.observableArray([]);
        App.requests.classificacoes.send();
        alert("initialize");
    }
});
```

Com este código em cima resolve o problema mais evidente.
Porém não compreendo como quer usar o `this.classificacoes.push(classificacoes);` uma vez que o ajax é asincrono.

Não seria caso de fazer o pedido e no onSuccess então instanciar a Classe `App.viewModels.selectsProcedimentos`? ou fazer o `.push()` para a propriedade da Classe que guarda essa array com `App.viewModels.selectsProcedimentos.classificacoes.push(classificacoes);`

Comment: Realmente estou tendo dificuldades para achar o melhor jeito de fazer isto. A questão é que são 4 selects, este é só o primeiro, com os outros vou ter que puxar por AJAX depois de qualquer jeito. Eu vou fazer o seguinte: vou criar o Request dentro da classe mesmo. Assim que der certo atualizo a pergunta com a solução.

Comment: @Andrey quer dizer a Classe Knockout dentro do Request do MooTools e não "Request dentro da classe", certo? Se Colocar esses 4 selects num jsFiddle e postar aqui posso dar uma olhada.

Comment: Eu quis dizer fazer `new Request({...}).send();` dentro da minha classe do viewModel. Não fiz o JSFiddle porque o AJAX dele nunca funcionou direito pra mim.

Comment: @Andrey, porque não faz `classificacoes` sendo um `computed`? No momento em que o `computed` for "evaluado" pelo `knockout`, você faz o request. Isso é bom porque se você usar qualquer `observable` dentro do `computed`, ao alterar o valor do `observable`, o `computed` é "reevaluado".

Comment: @Wakim Estou começando com Knockout. Como funciona o computed? Eu faço a requisição AJAX dentro dele e retorno? `ko.computed(function() { return "meu array json" });`? O problema é que a requisição é assíncrona.

Comment: É, pensando bem não vale a pena, porque você teria que criar uma "flag" `observable` para criar uma dependência e forçar a "reavaliação" do `computed`. Isso só vale a pena se o AJAX para recuperar os valores de `classificacoes` depender de algum outro valor que pode mudar. Acho que não vai cair bem no seu caso.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui fazer da seguinte maneira:

Javascript:

```js
App.viewModels.selectsProcedimentos = new Class({
    initialize: function(classificacoes) {
        this.classificacoes = ko.observableArray(classificacoes);
    }
});

App.init.selectProcedimentos = function() {
    new Request.JSON({
        url: "/classificacoes.json",
        method: "get",
        onSuccess: function(classificacoes) {
            ko.applyBindings( new App.viewModels.selectsProcedimentos(classificacoes) );
        }
    }).send();
};
```

E o HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select data-bind="options: classificacoes,
                       optionsText: 'ds_classificacao',
                       optionsValue: 'id',
                       optionsCaption: 'Selecione uma Classificação'"
            class="form-control input-sm"></select>
</div>

<script>
    App.init.selectProcedimentos();
</script>
```

Agradeço a paciência do @Sergio e do @Wakim

Agora é quebrar a cabeça pra fazer os selects que são dependentes deste.